# Date from Json list is not getting displayed properly in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

The date in angular js is getting displayed like /Date(1494288000000)/ which is from asp.net list of objects.

```
<tr class="unread" data-ng-repeat="notification in Notifications | filter:q | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <input data-ng-model="arr[notification.NotificationId]" type="checkbox" value="{{notification.NotificationId}}" ng-checked="" ng-click="" class="mail-checkbox">
    </td>         
    <td class="view-message  dont-show">{{notification.Title}}</td>
    <td class="view-message ">{{notification.Message}}</td>
    <td class="view-message  text-right">{{notification.Date | date}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: provide the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var dateToDisplay = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6))); 
 return dateToDisplay;
```

This is to be included in the custom filter function.

```
  {{dateToDisplay | customFilterName | date}}
```

This is to display date in view page. First filter through custom filter and then again filter through date filter. Source [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date`.. Angular date filter have included `new Date()` conversion. We don't need to write extra code.

```js
angular.module('exApp',[])
       .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
          $scope.current = new Date();
          var d = 1494288000000; // number
          console.log(typeof d);
          $scope.ex ="1494288000000"; // string 
          console.log(typeof $scope.ex);
          $scope.me = Date($scope.ex);
          $scope.newDate = new Date(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
      {{ current | date: 'd-MM-y'}} <br>
   Converted :  {{newDate|date}} <br>Without Convert : {{ex|date}}<br>Extra convert: {{me|date}}
  </div>
</div>
```